# How can I make colcon work with a plain preset-based CMake project with multiple presets in parallel?

Tags: cmake, build, cmake-presets, colcon

### Prologue

I have a [preset-based](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) plain CMake project so that I can build and test it with `cmake --preset $PRESET && cmake --build --preset $PRESET && ctest --preset $PRESET`. Note that it nicely interacts with [Microsoft's CMake Tools extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools&ssr=false#overview), be it for building, testing, debugging and Intellisense.

Since I want to handle multiple presets in parallel, I set `CMakePresets.json`'s [`binaryDir`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#configure-preset) property to `${sourceDir}/build/${presetName}/`.

### Issue

I want to also build this plain CMake project with [colcon](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/index.html). `colcon build --cmake-args "--preset $PRESET"` doesn't work, though, as it produces

```
WARNING:colcon.colcon_cmake.task.cmake.build:Could not build CMake package 'root_project_name' because the CMake cache has no 'CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME' variable
```

`root_project_name` being the argument to CMake's `project()` command in the top `CMakeLists.txt`.

How can I resolve this warning and the subsequent build failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Straightforward solution

Not setting `CMakePresets.json`'s [`binaryDir`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#configure-preset) property at all works fine with colcon, but doesn't allow for multiple preset builds in parallel.

### Solution with multiple preset builds in parallel

The reason for this behavior is [colcon-core](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core)'s `build` verb's passing the build base directory (default: `build`) suffixed by the found package's name (here: `root_project_name`) to the [colcon-cmake](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-cmake) extension [here](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/blob/e65ae4d281f8cb0e8a8e172b5615b62038912640/colcon_core/verb/build.py#L49).

The solution is to pass the correct build base to colcon (i.e. `colcon build --build-base ./build/$PRESET/ --cmake-args "--preset $PRESET"`) and to adapt your `CMakePresets.json`'s [`binaryDir`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#configure-preset) property to `${sourceDir}/build/${presetName}/root_project_name/`.

Note that this then works with `colcon test` as well, i.e. `colcon test --build-base ./build/$PRESET/ --ctest-args "--preset $PRESET"`.